# Issue: My new WordPress plugin appends a number "1" on install

Tags: wordpress

I just wrote my first plugin, a very basic routine that inserts a form on a page via shortcode.

Plugin runs fine on my local dev site, but when I upload and activate, it appends a "1" to the end of the foldername as if there were a duplicate folder there already, which there is not. Thus: "my_plugin_name" becomes "my_plugin_name1" And of course, the plugin won't function.

Any ideas on this, what to look for?

Here's the code:

```
/* Load the php file */
require_once('msc-mini-storage-calc.php');


/* Enqueue CSS file */
    function prefix_add_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url('msc-style.css', __FILE__) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_add_stylesheet' );



/* Register and enqueue the script*/
function load_msc_mini(){
wp_register_script( 'msc-mini-storage-calculator', plugins_url('msc-mini-storage-calculator.js', __FILE__ ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'msc-mini-storage-calculator' );
}

add_action('init', 'load_msc_mini');



/* Add function to load the form and add shortcode */
function show_calc_form(){
return $options = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( plugins_url() . '/msc-mini-storage-calc/mini-storage-calc_form.html' ) );
}
add_shortcode('msc-mini-calc', 'show_calc_form');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changed name of zip file and associated paths. I don't know why this was a fix but it did fix the issue.